# Ubuntu 14.04.1-amd64 crashes on startup from DVD during installation -- possibly video card driver?

Tags: drivers, ati

I have never used Linux and was trying to install Ubuntu so I can have Windows/Ubuntu dual boot. However, I cannot quite get to the installation screen. It starts loading from the DVD (or USV drive) and after awhile I just get a scrambled screen and frozen computer. I checked the forums and it seems that the video card may be the culprit: AMD Radeon HD 6450. Unfortunately I cannot get to Ubuntu (load it for trial or install it) in order to try to fix the problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

P.S. Please remember that I have never used Linux before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install with minimal-cd

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

To install, boot your computer from the the Minimal CD and type "cli" (command line install) at the prompt.

You can then follow the instructions from the text-based installer.

The official Ubuntu Installation Guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation